# Post on friends facebook wall using android

Tags: android, facebook

I need to post something into friends wall using android app. I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479763/post-to-specific-friends-facebook-wall).

I am using Facebook Android SDK 3.0, now I can successfully login to facebook using app.

I want to know what is the **mFacebook** mention in the above link.

Comment: actually i don't know what is mFacebook.I can,t implement my stuff without knowing about mFacebook.please tell me what is mFacebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class inside that library (Facebook Graph API) called "Facebook", which has several methods.
One of which is "authorize".

**mFacebook** is object of **Facebook** class.

See link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ and https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed

Comment: Thanks a lot.Facebook class is deprecated in android facebook sdk 3.0